# error connecting to the vysor app running on ios

Tags: vysor

[image]

I want to connect my ipohne to windows. but its howing this error. I have coonected it to my windows laptop via the lighning cabel. also downloadedthe beta app. nothing showing there too rather than redeem button. how can I fix this. please help

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure Apple iTunes is installed on your computer. It will fix the issue.